# how to pass templateRef to directive?

Tags: angular

i am trying to create a custom tooltip directive in angular and i want to pass templateRef as input property to that directive from parent component but templateRef.elementRef is returning a comment instead of template content.

**Directive:**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[tooltip]'
})
export class tooltipDirective {
  @Input('tooltip') tooltip: ElementRef<any>;
  @Input('placement') placement: string = 'bottom';

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
    console.log(this.tooltip);
  }
}
```

**Parent Component:**

```
<div [tooltip]="tooltipTemplate"> show tooltip </div>

<ng-template #tooltipTemplate>
  <div class="tooltip">
    tooltip text
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

how can i get actual content?

Comment: Don’t use the constructor (ever.. really).. try the AfterViewInit hook..

Comment: @MikeOne, Afterviewinit also gives the same result

Comment: Ah yeah.. sorry. I missed that you use an Input and not a viewChild.. not sure how to pass this to be honest..

Comment: ok no problem, thanks for your response

Answer (score 2):

you can use in the getter, but be carefull, the template is a [TemplateRef](https://angular.io/api/core/TemplateRef). If you want to add it, inject [viewContainerRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef) in the constructor, some like:

```
  _tooltip:TemplateRef<any>
  @Input('tooltip') set tooltip(value)
  {
    this._tooltip=value
    this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this._tooltip)
  }
  @Input('placement') placement: string = 'bottom';

  constructor(private viewContainer:ViewContainerRef) {}
```

**Updated**: About the use of a `this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this._tooltip)` in general we make some like

```
    const embeddedViewRef = this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView( this._tooltip );
    embeddedViewRef.detectChanges(); //<--this makes that if our template
                                     //has a variable and change, the tooltip
                                     //take account this change
```

Then, for make a tool, we can use Renderer2 to create a div and add to the div all the nodes of embeddedViewRef

```
  const div = this.renderer.createElement("span");
  embeddedViewRef.rootNodes.forEach(n => {
    this.renderer.appendChild(div, n);
  });
```

Well the hard work is calculate the position, create the class tooltip and add two HostListener for mouseout and mouseover

Comment: what is the role of createEmbeddedView?

Comment: @jagjeet, I update the answer to give some clue to make a tooltip,

Comment: @Elison Thanks a lot this is perfect, there is only one issue, with this approach i cannot add context to template while using it

Comment: i have found a solution for this by using a helper component along with directive i will update here if that works